# A polynomial satisfying a particular condition must be of the form $p(z)=cz^{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying assignment question of an institute in which I don't study and got struck on this particular question .

> Question: If p is a polynomial such that |p(z)|=p(|z|)for all z prove that $p(z)=c z^{n}$ for some c$\geq$ 0 and some n$\in \mathbb{N} \cup {0}$.

I took the polynomial as $p(z)=a_n z^n + ...+a_0 $and used the condition $p(z)=c z^{n}$ but I have no idea on which result to use now . So , I am clueless on what should be done now. I don't have anything else to show as attempt.

Kindly guide on how to prove this .
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(z)=0$ for some $z \neq 0$ then $0=|p(z)|=p(|z|)$ which give $p(|z|)=0$. But then  $p(\zeta)=0$ for every $\zeta$ with $|\zeta|=|z|$ so $p$ has infinitely many zeros. This implies that $p(z) \equiv 0$. Thus the only zero of $p$ is $0$. Can you finish?